# Erro Tesseract.js localização do LangPath

Tags: tesseract

Bom galera. estou com esse erro :

> AdaptedTemplates != NULL:Error:Assert failed:in file
>   ../classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 190 index.js:8 Uncaught abort() at
>   Error
>       at Na (https:// c dn. rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:36:26)
>       at Object.ka [as abort] (https:/ /c dn. rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:511:108)
>       at _abort (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:377:173)
>       at $L (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:387:55709)
>       at jpa (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:392:22274)
>       at lT (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:391:80568)
>       at mT (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:391:80700)
>       at Array.BS (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:391:69011)
>       at bP (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:387:110121)
>       at jT (h ttps://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js-core/0.1.0/index.js:391:80280)
>   If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can
>   give more information.

Estou criando o langPath e aplicando da seguinte maneira.

```
window.Tesseract = Tesseract.create({          
            langPath: '/app/modules/teste/tessdata/'
        })



    Tesseract.recognize(file, {
        lang: 'Inconsolata',
                tessedit_char_whitelist: '0123456789',
                langPath : '/app/modules/teste/tessdata/'

    })
        .progress(function(packet){
            console.info(packet)
                        console.log('é aqui? ^');
            progressUpdate(packet)

        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data)
                        console.log('ou aqui aqui? ^')
            progressUpdate({ status: 'done', data: data })
        });
```

A pasta está com permissão. Não sei oque pode esta errado Alguém ?

Comment: Ben vindo ao Stack Overflow, por favor especifique melhor o que está fazendo, compartilhe parte do seu código que causa o erro.. abs.

Comment: Mudei a pergunta lá ve se pode me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Me baseando nesse [Issue](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/173) e um pouco que conheço desta ferramenta:

**1-** No seu projeto está criando já o arquivo eng.traineddata, então toda vez que você manda executar seu código ele automaticamente já identifica onde está esse arquivo. E você está mudando a rota dele, daí talvez ele entre em conflito com os arquivos.

**2-** Verifique em seu código se você está chamando o eng.traineddata e se você possui esse arquivo dentro do seu projeto. Sem esse arquivo o Tesseract ele não haverá um "idioma". Nesse [wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#languages-and-scripts) você poderá encontrar a lista de todos as linguagens aceitas pelo Tesseract, e [aqui](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) você obterá os arquivos .traineddata com as linguagens aceitas.